# WHERE Clause on list of list in orientdb 3.0

Tags: java, orientdb3.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Df9hj.jpg)

I am try to run where clause on relTypeId or relTypeName using IN operator by passing multiple relTypeName or relTypeId. This values are part of traversing from one vertex to another.

I tried executing below command

```
SELECT FROM vertex WHERE relTypeName in ['Is KDE Process', 'Hello'];
```

but it didn't work.
But when i do

```
SELECT FROM vertex WHERE relTypeName contains list('Is KDE Process');
```

it returns result.
The problem with this i am not able to find out what is the syntax for passing multiple value.

Comment: I found the answer for this.

Comment: SELECT  INE('edege_name')[edge_property.Id IN [1]].RelationshipType.Id as relTypeId, Id as rootId FROM vertex